# What are general guide lines for reversing COM objects

Tags: windows

I'm interested in revers engineer COM objects. How can I find interfaces that a particular object implements if I know what interface it is?

Please tell if I need to change or rephrase the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to reverse engineer the COM library programatically, you should refer to [Improve Your Debugging by Generating Symbols from COM Type Libraries](https://web.archive.org/web/20161023092604/https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0399/comtype/comtype.aspx)

If you're looking to reverse engineer the COM library statically via IDA Pro, you can use [Class Informer](http://www.macromonkey.com/bb/index.php/topic,13.0.html).

If you're looking to reverse engineer the COM library via a nice GUI, I recommend [COMView](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/COMView.shtml).

Comment: Regarding COM Type libs - if I understood correctly from the article, I need the ```TLB``` files to be able to generate the symbols? If I only have a ```dll``` file, I'm in trouble?

Comment: You don't need the .TLB file since the type information is embedded in the COM library's PE resources.

Comment: TLB is *usually* embedded (especially if it's an ActiveX object or intended to be used for Automation) but it's not actually guaranteed.

Comment: What tips can you give if there is no type information in the file?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0399/comtype/comtype.aspx works fine for me -- http://i.imgur.com/IjdM3NO.png