# What are guidelines to find COM functions definition through a proxy DLL?

Tags: debugging, com

I've successfully reverse a DLL file which uses a COM interface and found the Class ID (CLSID) and Interface ID (IID). In Visual Studio debugging memory, it shows `S_OK` with `CoCreateInstance()` and all the function pointers of that COM interface. I saw this [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/what-are-general-guide-lines-for-reversing-com-objects) but that uses IDA to reverse a DLL.

I've followed an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20070428122627/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/hdevos/archive/2004/03/15/2936.aspx) which shows finding methods definition using Visual Studio debug mode. I've both CLSID and IID from which I get the interface pointer.

So, my question is how can I find the (undocumented) function definitions? Is there any easy general guidelines to follow? It will be easy if someone show an procedure with Visual Studio, reversing with IDA is bit more complex.

---

**Update:** According to the answer I reverse the DLL in IDA but the assembly shows the

```
off_180002230   dq offset off_1800023D0 ; DATA XREF: .rdata:off_180002480↓o
                dq offset ILxssUserSession
                dq offset IUnknown_QueryInterface_Proxy
                dq offset IUnknown_AddRef_Proxy
                dq offset IUnknown_Release_Proxy
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient3
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient4
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient5
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient6
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient7
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient8
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient9
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient10
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient11
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient12
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient13
                dq offset ObjectStublessClient14
unk_1800022B8   db  22h ; "             ; DATA XREF: .rdata:0000000180002DE0↓o
```

How can I relate those offset to a real function pointer? The current DLL is a proxy stub DLL and the real function is implemented/defined in another DLL. I've also seen this [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2822/com-interface-methods) which shows to follow function pointers.

Comment: For those who want to disassemble a COM interface, load PDB file in IDA. This helps me to disassemble it. Also you may use simple structs within structs as a inherited class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in general you follow the code flow from DllGetClassObject and find the code which creates COM classes depending on clsid and iid. Due to COM methods are virtual methods of C++ class, you'll be able to find VTBL for each COM class, and from there determine how many methods it has. Then you reverse each method to understand how many arguments it has and which are the types of arguments.

Comment: the only way is through disassembling. IDA may recognize the arguments count automatically, but the types of the arguments are up to you to reverse engineer. Also pay attention to the fact that COM methods pass the pointer to _this_ as stack argument, not via ECX. I.e. first argument in COM methods is always _this_.

Comment: each pointer in vtable points to the function code, which you need to disasseble. One by one.

Comment: It depends on the class hierarchy. Yes the first 3 methods in ppv are always QueryInterface, AddRef and Release due to all COM classes are derived from IUnknown. If the class is derived from IDispatch (which is derived from IUnknown), then there's going to be GetTypeInfoCount, GetTypeInfo, GetIDsOfNames and Invoke. And after those, there will be own methods of the COM class.

Comment: Ia asked if the offsets are different in 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: Yep, these ppv items are pointers, so in 32bit code the offsets will be a multiple of 4, in x64 - multiple of 8. Ex 0, 4, 8 vs 0, 8, 0x10 etc.